# Nesting ArrayList

Tags: gwt, treeview

I'm using GWT with java to build a [Tree](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Tree.html), and that tree should have some nested trees within it, and they should have too, and so on. So this is how I implement it (Tree extension is for neat add-method e.g "addCounty","addContinent" etc.):

```
public class myTree extends Tree {
    ArrayList <TreeItem> countries = null;
    ArrayList <ArrayList<TreeItem>> continents = null;
    ArrayList <ArrayList<ArrayList<TreeItem>>> geo = null;
    public myTree (){
        super();
        countries = new ArrayList<TreeItem>();
        continents = new ArrayList<ArrayList<TreeItem>>();
        geo = new ArrayList <ArrayList<ArrayList<TreeItem>>>();
        geo.add(continents);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I have a feeling this is not the right approach. The tree should have a lot more nodes, but for simplicity I kept only three. Any suggestions on how to implement it correctly? (I though just using ArrayList without instantiating, but is that the right approach?)

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but if you're using Java, what's wrong with using the built in Tree classes?

Comment: There are no built in `Tree` classes in java.

Answer (score 1):

You need a **tree** datastructure which is rather easy to implement in the first place:

```
public class Tree<T> {
    private Node<T> rootNode;

    public Tree(T satelliteData) {
        root = new Node<T>();
        root.setSatelliteData(satelliteData);
    }

    public static class Node<T> {
        private T satelliteData;
        private Node<T> parent;
        private List<Node<T>> children = new ArrayList<T>();

        // add getters/setters
    }
    // getters setters omitted
}
```

If I need to add functionality to a data structure like this I usually create **decorators** . In can prevent you from turning your `Tree` into a `God` object.

I omitted interfaces for brewity so this is a rather crude and simple implementation. Using a data structure like this you can greatly simplify traversal for example since it supports an arbitrary size both in breadth and depth.

Comment: The OP is actually talking about the `Tree` widget in GWT, which is a _treeview_ widget with its own data structure in the form of nested `TreeItem`s.

Comment: I know but the structure he described does not work with arbitrary depth. I do not know GWT so I don't have insight to its internals.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why you manage lists of `TreeItem`s: a `TreeItem` itself contains its child `TreeItem`s. Actually, both `Tree` and `TreeItem` implement [`HasTreeItems`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HasTreeItems.html) so you can treat them equally as `TreeItem` containers (whether they contain the root nodes or child nodes).

As for extending `Tree`, don't do it. Doing it means anyone using your `MyTree` could mess with the tree nodes in unpredictable ways, possibly breaking your code that expects a given number of levels, possibly some specific [user objects](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TreeItem.html#getUserObject%28%29) on the items, etc. (moreover if you dual-manage the items in both lists and the tree!)